# Activemq stomp jetty

Tags: jetty, activemq-classic, stomp

What i am trying to do is sending a message between 20-120KB using stomp via websocket to a topic 
and the error below is thrown, i tried to increase the requestBufferSize and ResponseBuffersize to value of 512000 without any effect. Any help is appreciated.

> WARN | handle failed java.lang.IllegalStateException: FULL   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketParserD00.parseNext(WebSocketParserD00.java:104)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketConnectionD00.handle(WebSocketConnectionD00.java:164)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:545)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:43)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Answer (score 1):

Primary issue I see is that you appear to be using the very first draft of the websocket protocol.  That is indicated by the D00 in your stack trace.

You want to be using the RFC6455 version as that is effectively the websocket protocol now.

WebSocketConnectionRFC6455 and so on..

Use the latest 7.6.x or 8.1.x release of jetty and fix any references to the old draft version.  Those drafts have been kept for some backwards compatibility and will likely be removed sooner or later.

(so its clear the protocol was not backwards compatible for changes until about draft 13 I think it was...so this is likely a protocol mismatch)

Comment: I Used jetty 7.6.1 the problem is the same  WARN | Text message too large > 16384 chars for . the problem is that the maxTestMessageSize is 16*1024 in class org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketClient